# The package of an MVC application in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, model-view-controller, jakarta-ee, architecture

I am developping an app which has the MVC architecture.  I would like to know how should I make the packages for each component (model,view,control)?

Is a package for Web pages, a package for EJBs and DAO? And of course an EAR which contains all the 3 projects

Thanks for help I would appreciate it.

Comment: Could you please retype the question? I'm having difficulty understanding what you are trying to say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I think you need to understand MVC (Model, View, Controller).

A model is a class that will manipulate data. For example, a model at a very basic level could be a class that will only keep track of how many dogs you have.

A view is the part of the application that the user interfaces with. In our dog application, this would be the graphical user interface or the command line interace that the user types into, or interacts with buttons.

The Controller is the code in the project that after the view is interacted with, then tells the data where to go, for instance tell the model to increment or decrement the amount of dogs that you have. The controller would also be button listeners in the application.

You're structure for your application should be like this:

```
/
 main file
 model/
 view/
 controller/
```

You should try this link: [what is Model in MVC pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10345961/what-is-model-in-mvc-pattern)

Comment: So the DAO  ( data access Object) will be in the Model layer?

Comment: I put my DAOs in a seperate package, is that bad practice? Should they go in the model. Is it okay to have other packages besides Model, View and Controller e.g. Utils, Listeners,api?